# Restricting Domain of 3D Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I have this 3D plot:

[image]

I would like to plot the function *only* over the region over the darker half of the bottom (the part closer to us).

Here is a MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
zmax=15,
zmin=0,
view = {45}{45},
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(Tan), color=(Tan)},
xlabel = $s$,
ylabel = $h$,
zlabel = {$f(s,h)$},
ticks = none,
]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=30,
domain=0:1.5,
%y domain = 0:x, %does not work
opacity=0.5,
]
{12*exp(-(4*x+3*y))};

%highlighting dark part of bottom
\filldraw[Tan, fill = Tan, opacity = 0, fill opacity = 0.5] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0) -- (1.5,0,0) -- (0,0,0);

%line across bottom
\draw[RawSienna, thick, opacity = 0.75] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0);

%line going across graph
\addplot3 [domain=0:1.5, RawSienna, thick, samples=30, samples y=0, opacity = 0.75] (x,x,{12*exp(-(7*x))});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use `y domain = 0:x`, but that does not even compile (it takes too long and then craps out). Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe add a link to the previous question. This is a follow-up, or not?

Comment: Haha it actually is the same question I'm working on, but the nature of this TeX problem I'm having is different from the last.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this? (Note that if you want a very old version instead of `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` this will have to be slightly modified, i.e. the coordinates in `\clip` need to be prepended with `axis cs:`, 
`\clip plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1.5] (axis cs:\x,\x,{f(\x,\x)})
 -- (axis cs:1.5,0,{f(1.5,1.5)}) -- (axis cs:0,0,{f(1.5,1.5)}) -- (axis cs:0,0,{f(0,0)});`. )

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table,x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=12*exp(-(4*\x+3*\y));}]

\begin{axis}[
zmax=15,
zmin=0,
view = {45}{45},
grid=minor,
colormap={mycol}{color=(Tan), color=(Tan)},
xlabel = $s$,
ylabel = $h$,
zlabel = {$f(s,h)$},
ticks = none,
]

\begin{scope}
 \clip plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1.5] (\x,\x,{f(\x,\x)})
 -- (1.5,0,{f(1.5,1.5)}) -- (0,0,{f(1.5,1.5)}) -- (0,0,{f(0,0)});
 \addplot3[
 surf,
 samples=30,
 domain=0:1.5,
 %y domain = 0:x, %does not work
 opacity=0.5,
 ] {f(x,y)};
\end{scope}

%highlighting dark part of bottom
\filldraw[Tan, fill = Tan, opacity = 0, fill opacity = 0.5] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0) -- (1.5,0,0) -- (0,0,0);


%line across bottom
\draw[RawSienna, thick, opacity = 0.75] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,1.5,0);

line going across graph
\addplot3 [domain=0:1.5, RawSienna, thick, samples=30, samples y=0, opacity = 0.75] 
(x,x,{f(x,x)});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: This will go in to by code bucket :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I had in mind! For what reason did you say the code will have to be modified in ```\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}```? Because it works fine for me!

Comment: @AidenKenny That's a typo. I wanted to write: "Note that **if** you want a very old version instead of \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} this will have to be slightly modified.", the reason being that with very old versions you need to prepend the coordinates in `\clip` with `axis cs:`.

Comment: @AidenKenny Thanks for spotting this! It was indeed very misleading.